What is $P$ in axial deformation formula in these cases?
We know that for a rod with constant cut section and material properies:
$\delta=\frac{PL}{AE}$
I know what is P in a simple case, such as a free rod in tension, it is just the tension force.
If the rod is fixed on one side and is pulled on the other, the tension force is equal to the reaction, and this is $P$.
What about this case:

What is $P$ for each rod? is that the net force on each? If so, how is that calculated?
Also, If $P$ is the net force on a body, then think about a free rod in tension. The net force is $0$ but it still streches, so $\delta \neq 0$. But from the formula if $P=0$ then $\delta= 0$
$E$ is constant in all sections

This is an example of a statically indeterminate problem where you can't just get the answer by drawing free body diagrams.  It's possible to intuit that you need to consider the stiffness in the answer by thinking about the stiffness of the middle thick section (only).  If it were made of jello with infinitessimally small E, then the reaction force at A would be $-P_B$ and the reaction force at D would be $-P_C$.  If it was infinitely stiff, then the reaction forces would be $+/- (P_C + P_B)$ added vectorially and assuming no preload or thermal effects.
It's not clear from the problem if $E$ is constant for all the sections but you will need to consider the deflections of each section as well as the relevant FBDs.  One way to check your answer is to see if it conforms to the extreme example conditions above.
Addendum:
Noting that it's a possibility in the real world, neglect preload and/or thermal effects as already stated.  Assume for simplicity that $L_2 = L_1$ (although it's not really needed). To clarify, I will RENAME $P_B$ and $P_C$ in your diagram as $F_B$ and $F_C$ so that internal forces are $P$s and external applied forces are $F$s. Call the internal forces in the rods (i.e. what you were looking to find) $P_A$, $P_B$, and $P_C$.  All $P$ are assumed positive in tension and all $F$ are assumed positive to the right (not as in the original case). Part of the confusion in the problem is caused by mixing internal and external forces with the same denoting letter $P$ and having forces defined as positive in different directions.  Setting the problem up clearly and consistently is half the battle.
If we assume the forces $F_B$ and $F_C$ act on little rigid massless segments then we can draw a pseudo-free-body-diagram as follows.

I say "pseudo" FBD because it's a kind of combination of different FBDs to save time and space, so you have to be a little careful when you do this as a short cut.  Nonetheless, taking the system as a whole, it's clear that
$-P_A + F_B + F_C + P_C = 0$.
Doing individual FBDs at the rigid/massless interfaces (black and grey blocks), you get
$-P_A + F_B + P_B = 0 $  and $-P_B + F_C + P_C = 0 $.
You might think that's three equations and three unknowns, but unfortunately they are redundant (adding the last two gives you the first one).  So you need another equation. What else do you know?
Well, you know that the total deflection of the bars has to equal zero.
$\delta_A + \delta_B + \delta_C = 0$
where  $\delta_A = \frac{P_A L_A}{A_A E_A}$ and so on. Because we defined the $P$ as positive in tension, the same is true for the $\delta$s.  If we do the math right, some will be positive and some will be negative.  Now express the $\delta$s as functions of the $P$s and include the different $A$, $L$, etc.  Essentially what you are doing is accounting for stiffness effects to augment your original FBD equations.  Now you have three full rank equations and can solve for the $P$s.  Again, if some turn out to be negative, that just means that they are in compression and not tension.

$E$ is constant in all sections. But my question was what is the defenition $P$ in the axis deformation formula

See my addendum above.

So if $P$ is the internal tension force, then by cutting at each segment and then adding internal force at the cut, the normal forces you draw near the massless parts cancel out and by equilibrium I get $P_b=P_a-F_b$. Now this is the third equation and the problem is solved right?

This is what would be the "second equation" following the addendum above.  It comes from force balance on the massless connector on the left (the massless condition isn't actually relevant - it's infinite rigidity that is the important consideration there).  Doing the same on the right side doesn't get you additional information.  So the the "third" equation to use is $\delta_A + \delta_B + \delta_C = 0$ but written to include the $P$s.
